# Variable reference from external script in jsdom

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

Below is the minimal example of jsdom code which uses the `script` parameter. Despite of all the attempts trying to find out a way to refer to the external JSs, I keep getting this

> ReferenceError: exVar is not defined

Does anyone know what is the problem here and how to fix it?

**stackOverTest.js**

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env({
    "html": "<html><body></body></html>",
    scripts: [__dirname + "exScript.js"],
    done: function(er, win) {
    console.log("exVar: ", exVar);
    }
});
```

**exScript.js**

```
var exVar = "test";
```

Comment: Try `__dirname + "/exScript.js"`

Comment: @laggingreflex, your suggestion didn't help, unfortunately

Comment: Is your `exScript.js` in the same directory as your `stackOverTest.js`?

Comment: @laggingreflex, yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use win scope: `console.log("exVar: ", win.exVar);` and `__dirname + "/exScript.js"`

Comment: `exVar` is undefined in the scope of `win`. I don't actually understand why `window` is relevant for use of external scripts?

Comment: You tried to do what I suggested? Show me the final script please.

Comment: my mistake! I didn't notice the second half of your answer, which was already mentioned in the comment to my first post. now it, works! thanks!

Comment: As of v10, jsdom has a new API. To use this syntax you should change the import to: `const jsdom = require('jsdom/lib/old-api.js');` See the [readme](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) for more details.